# SignalR PersistentConnection Cathcing Ping or Send Custom Ping by js client

Tags: asp.net, signalr

On server side  I have

```
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        private static List<UserInfo> _Users;
        public static List<UserInfo> Users
        {
            get { return Global._Users; }
            set
            {
                lock (_Users)
                {
                    Global._Users = value;
                }
            }
        }
    ...

       public class RawHub : PersistentConnection
        {

            protected override Task OnConnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
            {
                var UserID = request.QueryString.Where(t => t.Key == "U");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserID.First().Value))
                {
                    var ui = new Guid(UserID.First().Value);
                    var user = Global.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.USERID == ui);
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        var us = new UserInfo();
                        us.USERID = ui;
                        us.ConnectionId = connectionId;
                        Global.Users.Add(us);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        user.ConnectionId=connectionId;
                    }
                    return Connection.Send(user.ConnectionId,"Good To Go");
                }            
            }
```

I want to tryout send users their specific infos user by user with Send ...
bu I have to clean up Global.Users when they are disconnected.

Q: Is that possible to catch pings ? from js client or must i have to ping to client to detect live or not ?

What is the best approach

thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May br you can send custom i am alive messages from js client. Becouse some times ping doesnot come from client as expected. Usually when network is busy this happens...

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly is the problem here but you can simply listen for messages/pings in OnReceived

asp.net/signalr

Comment: How can i detect connection is not working for a user 10 sec. So decide to remove that user from Galobal.Users list ?
What is the best way

Comment: So, ideally the OnDisconnected method on the server should be triggered when a client disconnects...but if you notice that OnDisconnected is not being called in some cases...you can define a custom hear beat from client to server and take appropriate action if you don't hear from the client

Comment: is this makes network twisted or something un expected ? Why there is not built in watchable life time events ? or is there i am missing some point?